# how to place comma in django templates

Tags: django-templates

I would like to output the following using django templates:

```
Manhattan, NY, USA
```

with the following code:

```
{{ city }}, {{ state }}, {{ country }}
```

But sometimes one or more of those variables might be empty. Let's say the state variable is empty, then the output will look like this:

```
Manhattan, , USA
```

So my question is what is the best way of dealing with commas without using multiple if statements.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a template filter to achieve this, but I'm unaware of it.  As such, I'd write my own template filter to add a string to the end of my values.  It would be used like this:

```
{{ city|suffix:", " }}{{ state|suffix:", " }}{{ country }}
```

Information on creating custom template filters can be found in the Django documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Your template filter would look something like this:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='suffix')
@stringfilter
def suffix(value, arg):
    "Suffixes a string with the argument, only if the string is not empty"
    if value:
         return value + arg
    return value
```

Although this will only work if `country` is always supplied.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think it's great. But there might be some cases where this might not work. For example, what would the code yield when the city and state are present, but country is empty? I think it would result in "Manhattan, NY, ".

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the variables in a list and use the join filter or a for loop with a single if statement. Though either of these solutions would affect the clarity and readability of your template and I tend to prefer if statements in such cases especially if more complex HTML is involved between the comma-separated items.